# How to get the assigned properties of an object initializer using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, roslyn

I have classes that specify hard coded values. An example looks like the following:

```cs
    [CodeGenAsValueObject]
    public class DfltTaxableTypes : WithEnumerablePropsOfType<TaxableType>
    {
        public static TaxableType Taxable = new TaxableType()
        {    // <-  I want what's inside of here specifically as Dict<string, object>
            TaxableTypeId = new Guid("7a702ec4-94a3-431b-8217-2b44ef0ae22a"),
            Name = "Taxable"
        };   //  <-  To here

        public static TaxableType NonTaxable = new TaxableType()
        {
            TaxableTypeId = new Guid("76eee771-cbdc-4a7b-95d5-0d6e0959bdff"),
            Name = "NonTaxable"
        };
    }
```

Assume `TaxableType` has many properties that otherwise I don't care about.

How can I using reflection get something like a `Dictionary<string, object>` of *assigned properties* for each static `TaxableType`?

I am using this in custom Code Generation for our Typescript clients so performance is not an issue.

What I have as a start:

```cs
    var dfltValObjContainers = myAssy.GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.CustomAttributes.Select(y => y.AttributeType)
            .ToList()
            .Contains(typeof(CodeGenAsValueObject)))
        .Distinct().ToList();
    
    var containerInstances= dfltValObjContainers.Select(x => {
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(x);
            // Could get all Fields' values where value != default(fieldType).. 
            // Would prefer a more direct get assigned properties of object initializer.
            var eaValueObj = x.GetFields().Select(f => {
                return f.GetObjectInitializersAsDict() // <- Need help here.
            }).ToList();
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: One (partial) suggestion is to compare each property's value to the default value for that property, assuming you don't initialize it to the default value.

Comment: @Paramecium13 - yeah that is my fallback if I don't get a better answer..  Recorded that in the comments of what I have started.

Comment: You could also try to reflect over the static construct of the class, I think that's where the initialization code will be, and find which properties you set on which objects. That will involve parsing IL though.

Comment: Are you trying to implement custom class based enumerations? You're wanting to be able to get a dictionary of all properties defined in your TaxableType? I assume the dictionary would contain a string key of the property name with an object representing the value of said property? Is your `TaxableType` class an abstract class or is it a concrete class? Do you only want to retrieve the properties defined in the `TaxableType` class, or do you want to also obtain any properties defined in the derived classes? A lot of questions but just trying to make sure I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: This is a long shot but if you're targeting .NET 5 you can use source generator and then hook into the `InitializerExpressionSyntax`.

Comment: @jandrew - Ignore the `WithEnumerablePropsOfType`  - I should have removed it for clarity.  I want a `Dictionary<string, object>` of whats inside the `{ }`s of the object initializer. `TaxableType` is just a class, there are no 'modifiers' on it.

Comment: @JohanP - source generators look awesome, but that would be a significant rewrite outside scope of this.  I actually generate my controllers from my EF Entities, and have to build generate build.  Would have been nice to have 2 years ago.

Comment: @ttugates I see what you're trying to do now. I'm fairly certain that there's not any simple way to do what you're asking without checking the value of each property returned by a `Type.GetMembers()` or similar search. I checked the API reference to see if there was anything in `BindingFlags` to specify a param to check the property values but there isn't. I would just do a standard `Type.GetMembers` or `Type.GetProperties` search and then use LINQ to check the value of each returned property. Check the `BindingFlags` enum and see what you can use to limit the amount of search returns.